# How to prevent loud beeps before alarm rings

Tags: applications, audio, alarm, wakelock

Using alarm xtreme on Samsung S8.

In the past it didnt happen but recently when the phone wakes up to play the alarm it plays a very loud 3 beeps and then starts the alarm.

The alarm is set to start quietly and raise but due to the beeps I wake up in panic.

Please advise

Comment: I'm using Alarm Clock Xtreme, which is what I assume you mean. I'm unable to reproduce your issue. So, what exact version are you using? Click the hamburger menu in the upper left corner, then **About us** (the exact words may differ, since I translated the localization back to English). And are you using Pro or the free version?

Comment: @DuaneDibbley the ver is 6.6.1.70000877
Thanks,
Nir

Comment: That's the same as I have. And like I said in my previous comment, I can't reproduce your issue. The only thing I can suggest now, is to dig through the various settings. The two that come to mind, are **Sound type** and **Override system volume** (again the exact words may differ), but if this is a bug, it may well be affected by seemingly unrelated settings too.

Comment: I received an update to Alarm Clock Xtreme just now. Since I can't reproduce your issue, I can't say if this update fixes it, but I thought I'd let you know that it's available anyway.